# Write Rewrite rules on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, global-asax, redirect

I'm using url rewrite module to IIS ( http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module ) and i want do dynamically add the rules based on a rules repository, instead of statically create them on web.config.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom providers like DBProvider and FileMapProvider and then create a job that reads your repository and fills the DB/file with your custom rules.
Check out this [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) for more information.